# Sencha Touch 2.2 build error in iOS

Tags: extjs, build, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch 2.0 project, have upgraded to sencha touch 2.2 moved the app folder from the 2.0 project to 2.2 project.
I have installed sencha cmd, it is working fine.
when trying to build the project, getting the following error

`[ERR] Failed to find file(s) for depdency reference /Users/mobcomp6/RSR/sencha/InfoImage(sencha2.2)/app/controller/common/workitems/CommonWIListController.js::ClassRequire::
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED`

the file CommonWIListController.js exists at the specified location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the File CommonWIListController.js had an error. cleared the error then the build was successful